# Show that two sets of solutions are actually identical.

Tags: trigonometry, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

### Specific

**Context**

Solve the equation $ \sin x = \cos 2x $.

**Problem**

One solution gave the general solution as

- $ x = \pi/6 + 2\pi n/3 $ or
- $ x = -\pi/2 - 2\pi n $ for any integer $n$.

But another solution gave the general solution

- $ x = \pi/6 + 2\pi n $ or
- $ x = 5\pi/6 + 2\pi n $ or
- $ x = 3\pi/2 + 2\pi n $ for any integer $n$.

> Show that these two sets of solutions are actually identical.

---

### General

> How does one, conceptually, prove that two sets of solutions are identical?

---

### Attempt

*@user254665 suggest I do the following (see comment under question). I'm not precisely sure what to make of my findings.* `:P`

- $ \pi/6 + 2\pi n/3 = \pi /6 + 2\pi m \implies n = 3m $
- $ \pi/6 + 2\pi n/3 = 5\pi /6 + 2\pi m \implies n = 1 + 3m $
- $ \pi/6 + 2\pi n/3 = 3\pi /2 + 2\pi m \implies n = 2 + 3m $
- $ -\pi /2 - 2\pi n = \pi /6 + 2\pi m \implies 3n = -1 - 3m $
- $ -\pi /2 - 2\pi n = 5\pi /6 + 2\pi m \implies 3n = -2 - 3m $
- $ -\pi /2 - 2\pi n = \pi /2 2\pi m \implies n = -1 - m $

I do notice *something* about the first 3 bullets: any integer $n$ can be produced by some integer $m$ in 1 of 3 equations.

However, I can't make heads or tails with my findings.

---

### Disclaimer

I have not taken any set-theory classes. The problem above was given in a trigonometry textbook. In case you need to explain some set-theory, please don't use unfamiliar notation without explaining it.

Comment: For example, if $n$ has the form $3k+1$ , the expression $2n/3+1/6$ is equivalent to $2k+5/6$. Try the other cases in a similar way.

Comment: To show that two sets $ A, B $ are  equal, use the method of proving that any $ x\in A $  belongs to $ B $ and that any $ y\in B $ belongs to $ A.  $ And note the error in  the last formula for the the second set, as pointed out by Bernard:  $ \sin x=\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2 x\iff$ $\sin x\in \{-1,1/2\} $. If $ n=1 $  then $ \sin (3\pi /2+n\pi)=1\not \in \{-1,1/2\}.$

Comment: @user254665: I've already fixed the error. Regarding `use the method`, what method do I use? I'm unfamiliar with proving such problems.

Comment: Write the second set with $m$ replacing $n$, Show that for any $m$ and any member $x$ of the  second set, there exists some $n$ that produces  the value $x$ as a member of the first set. And vice-versa.

Comment: @user254665: By "any $m$" and "some $n$", do you mean "any _integer_ $m$" and "some _integer_ $n$"?

Comment: @user254665: I've done the equating (see "Attempt" in question), but I can't see what I can do with the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I think I got it...*

---

### Preparation

In the attempt, I simplified the 6 equations to the following:

- $ n = 3m $
- $ n = 3m + 1 $
- $ n = 3m + 2 $
- $ 3n = -1 - 3m $
- $ 3n = -2 - 3m $
- $ n = -1 - m $

Let us take the first 3 and last equations. The rest are irrelevant.

---

### Prove: $n \in m$

See the equations:

- $ n = 3m $
- $ n = 3m + 1 $
- $ n = 3m + 2 $

When you plug any integer $m$, you will result in a integer $n$.

- $ n = 3m $ covers ... $-3$, $0$, $3$, $6$ ...
- $ n = 3m + 1 $ covers ... $-2$, $1$, $4$, $7$ ...
- $ n = 3m + 2 $ covers ... $-1$, $2$, $5$, $8$ ...

The combination of these sets results in ... $-3$, $-2$, $-1$, $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$ ...

---

### Prove: $m \in n$

See the equation $ n = -1 - m $.

It can be rewritten as $ m = -n - 1 $.

It immediately follows that any integer $n$ will result in all integers $n$.

---

### Answer

Indeed, both sets are identical.

---

### Disclaimer

I'd like to thank @user254665 for a hint which led me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check that, *modulo 2π*, the first set of solutions of the first series is
$$x=\frac\pi6,\quad \frac{5\pi}6,\quad\frac{9\pi}6=\frac{3\pi}2,$$
so it's the same as the (corrected) second series.

Also, observe the second set of this series is redundant.

Comment: I see what you're saying. However, is there a method without using modulo (the curriculum doesn't expect knowledge of modulo, so I suppose there is a simpler way)?

Comment: Modulo $2\pi$ is just an abbreviation for ${}+2n\pi\enspace(n\in\mathbf Z)$, so  replace it where required.